# Maven build doesn't execute a csv file reader

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, opencsv

I am not able to read values from csv file in a maven projects. Works perfectly when it is done using testng. Can Some one help me in knowing what else I am missing

Here's my code:
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

```
public static void Test() throws Exception
{

 @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("File"));
      String [] csvCell;

       while ((csvCell = reader.readNext()) != null)
      { 



         String A = csvCell[0];
         String B = csvCell[1];
}
Maven Dependency 
    <dependency>
 <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
 <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
 <version>3.9</version>
```

Comment: Do you mean CSV(MS DOS) format?

Comment: What part of your maven build do you expect to execute this code?

Comment: I want one of my function to fetch inputs from a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Try having the same dependency but with test scope

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
 <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
 <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
 <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
 <version>3.9</version>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Now I am getting a "package com.opencsv does not exist" error after adding <scope>

Comment: Also to mention this works absolutely fine when I run using testng build